# updating index settings through elasticsearch java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I am using Jest client libraries to connect and interface with my ES cluster. I was able to injest documents to an index sucessfully and specify settings.

```
 Settings.Builder settings = Settings.settingsBuilder();
 settings.put("number_of_shards", 5);
 settings.put("number_of_replicas", 1);
```

I am having issues with updating the settings that I have specified after indexing documents. The documentation doesn't seem to be clear on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

After an extensive google search, I found a solution. This can be achieved using the updatesettings class.

```
String body = "{ \"index\" : { " +
               "\"number_of_replicas\" :50" + ","+
               "} }";

UpdateSettings updateSettings = new UpdateSettings.Builder(body).addIndex(index).build();
```

Comment: It is giving me error at `addIndex`. Did this worked for you ?